# How to show data that is only above or below 10% of a 30 day average?

Tags: sql, between, average

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:
I have this written for a 30 Day look at files that produce a count once a day.

```
SELECT reuseid, hexample, hTimeframe, irodger, dateandtime
From reusing.reuse
WHERE hexample= 'RDM Daddy'
      and hTimeframe= 'TSBC0002.dlt.*.dat'
      and ((GETDATE()-dateandtime) < 32.0)
      and irodger<>(SELECT AVG(irodger) FROM reusing.reuse)
ORDER by dateandtime desc
```

I need to take the average of the past 30 days. Then I need to produce an error if the amount of the current day is +/-10% (*1.1/*.9)......

This current query produces the data over the past 30 days and shows me what is above or below the current average, but not what is in between.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this kind of operation can solve your problem :

```
SELECT reuseid, hexample, hTimeframe, irodger, dateandtime
From reusing.reuse
WHERE hexample= 'RDM Daddy'
      and hTimeframe= 'TSBC0002.dlt.*.dat'
      and ((GETDATE()-dateandtime) < 32.0)
      -- Here :
      and (irodger/(SELECT AVG(irodger) FROM reusing.reuse)) NOT BETWEEN 0.9 AND 1.1
ORDER by dateandtime desc
```

Comment: Thank you Aurel! The SQL seems to make perfect since but it does not seem to limit any of the results....Any further thoughts?

Comment: Correction--This query will run without any limiting using "NOT BETWEEN", but when I satisfy any requirments using the BETWEEN, I get no results shown. It can be blatent numbers that would cover all data ranges, but still no data appears....